# Set sSwfPath is not set in initialization

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have still to try it on a web server over localhost but I think that the issue could be somewhere else.

I am developing a solution in ASP.NET MVC with DataTables, the interaction between the two will be really light.

If I setup the desired SWF path in TableTools.js the full or the relative path to my resource it works

```
TableTools.DEFAULTS = {
"sSwfPath": "http://localhost:51203/Content/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
"sRowSelect":      "none",
"sSelectedClass":  null,
"fnPreRowSelect":  null,
"fnRowSelected":   null,
"fnRowDeselected": null,
"aButtons":        [ "copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf", "print" ],
"oTags": {
    "container": "div",
    "button": "a", // We really want to use buttons here, but Firefox and IE ignore the
                     // click on the Flash element in the button (but not mouse[in|out]).
    "liner": "span",
    "collection": {
        "container": "div",
        "button": "a",
        "liner": "span"
    }
}
```

};

If I try to pilot it in the component initialization it doesn't seem to assign it in the initialization.

```
$('.ReservationTable').dataTable({
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": ["copy"],
        "sSwfPath": "http://localhost:51203/Content/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
});
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that having multiple DataTables with the same class on the same page and trying to initialize multiple datatables in that way is fine but not for the oTableTools.

Changing to a separate initialization for each table by id will sorts this out.

```
$('#ReservationTable').dataTable({
"sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
"oTableTools": {
    "aButtons": ["copy"],
    "sSwfPath": "http://localhost:51203/Content/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
}
```

});